# How to set MSBuild to compile multiple times?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

In our current product, we have multiple solution files of visual studio and multiple projects in them.
All of them are interlinked and interdependent.
So, the 1st project is dependent on files created by 3rd and 3rd on 4th and 4th on 1st , etc.
So, if we compile 1st project it will fail as the 3rd is not generated the binary files yet, and we continue to compile the 2nd and it also fails and then 3rd, the 3rd will be successful as the 1st and 2nd are partially compiled and the relevant files are available.So once all the projects are compiled, I will retry the failed projects and they will be successful.

So to automate all this part, I have written scripts in python and in that I am doing the retry 5 times and failing the build process if the 5 times limit is completed.

The complete build process I have written my own logic in python.

The requirement now is, We want to switch from this custom written code to existing automation tools like Jenkins, so that it will be well structured.But I didn't see the project compilation retry option in MSBuild.

Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: I posted the same question in FB. But got some weird replies to change the complete Architecture. If we have the solution in languages like python to create our custom build scripts.

I think there will be solution for this in the existing tools also.I don't think what is the necessity of changing the product architecture to integrate it with jenkins.

To remove the same chain of communocation here.I am giving the summary of conversation happened in FB for this question.

Comment: To be more specific , the current product solution files is not having any issue with order but it's like circle...like both 1 and 2 project files are dependent on each other..so 1 is failing without 2 and 2 is successful as 1 is partially built..so I will retry 1 again after 2.. to make it success...but if I try 2 first then it will fail as files from 1 not available.. it is not feasible to change the code as complete structure changes

Comment: What you call 'project compilation retry option' simply doesn't exist (in that form) in MSBuild (or any other build system I've heard of), likely because it is a really crippled way of doing things. Get rid of cyclic dependencies, and just build in the correct order from the beginning. Either manually, or automatically be specifying dependencies betwee projects within a solution. Or, if you insist, just write an MSBuild file which builds each project 5 times, ignoring errors the first 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have several jobs in jenkins. Say we need to execute msbuild in the following order: A.sln, B.sln, C.sln

You will need 3 jenkins job. After Job A is executed, you will need to tell Jenkins trigger job B. After Job B is completed, trigger Job C.

There is a plugin called parameterized trigger which I have used previously:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

If say for e.g. you need artefacts from job A,you will need to execute a batch file step to copy dll to job B's workspace